# UltiSnips snippets not expanding in vim

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-ultisnips

I installed YouCompleteMe and UltiSnips together in order to use snippets.

Here is my `.vimrc`:

```
call plug#begin() 
Plug 'preservim/NERDTree'
Plug 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
call plug#end()

let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/.ycm_extra_conf.py'

" Trigger configuration. Do not use <tab> if you use https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe.
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger="<s-tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<c-b>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<c-z>"

" If you want :UltiSnipsEdit to split your window.
let g:UltiSnipsEditSplit="vertical"
```

I'm trying to expand snippets by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but instead of expanding it is reverse scrolling through suggestions. This happens even though I've updated in my `.vimrc` for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. What should I do now?

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim @AvneeshSirohi! Right now it's hard to understand what you want to accomplish with your question, can you please update it to describe the actual issue (for example, "The key binding of 'Shift+Tab' I configured for UltiSnips does not work as I expected it to, instead of doing X, it does Y." And also try to make it a question, even if it's simply "How can I fix it?" Please take some time to [edit] and improve your question, that should attract quality answers. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my question I hope it's clear now what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: Looks great, thanks! I further trimmed your sample vimrc to remove some of the blank and commented lines, so it looks a little more tidy. Cheers!

Comment: Try what is written in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/bq2drz/vim_plug_ultisnips_not_working/eo0s50a/).

Comment: @user938271, I tried above <c-g> don't work either for me. When I press c-g nothing happens.